# Why is my output report showing errors although it shows up normally when refreshing data in webi?

Tags: business-objects, webi

Why is my output report showing errors although it shows up normally when refreshing data in webi?

My excel file output is the first screenshot, the report view in webi is the second. I am able to export the data and the output is fine, when I run it under a schedule it results in the errors seen below, any help appreciated

[image: excel output]

[image: webi view]

Comment: Try scheduling the report in WebI format instead of Excel.  The scheduled report that's generated will likely show the same error, and you can then debug the problem in the report.

Comment: A very useful tip - I have managed to resolve the error, thanks!